# PHP regex to include additional criteria

Tags: php, regex

I have a php regex which works but I would like to modify it to include one more condition

```
preg_match_all('/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----[^-]*-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----/s', $file, $matches);
```

I am loading a file as a string which contains the following blocks of text

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIEezCCA2MCAQAwcjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDTALBgNVBAgMBFV0YWgxDTALBgNV
ObtIDOoce4eY4Z76AbLUDVuiIZEDI95Rlt6Ha5/DVJZtoljkVQ42RrmP/Yu26Xk=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
AHAAdABvAGcAcgBhAHAAaABpAGMAIABQAHIAbwB2AGkAZABlAHIDAQAwgc8GCSqG
SIb3DQEJDjGBwTCBvjAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBPAwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUH
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Currently the above regex catches the first block but not the second block, how can I improve the regex to catch both? The second block has an extra word `NEW`  in the header and footer. Ideally i would like a single regex to be flexible and catch either or.

Comment: yes, that worked. please make it an official answer so i can mark it as helpful

Comment: your original worked fine.. is this another variation?

Comment: the updated one you provided didnt work, the original one did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my earlier comment, maybe try either:

```
-----BEGIN (?:NEW )?CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----[^-]*-----END (?:NEW )?CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Or:

```
-{5}BEGIN ((?:NEW )?CERTIFICATE REQUEST-{5})[^-]*-{5}END \1
```

See how this handles your string [here](https://regex101.com/r/790zou/4). Key to what it is you are after is in both cases to include `(?:NEW )?` to optionally include the literal word "NEW". In my second pattern I simply caught this option including the repetitional text into a capture group which I used in a later reference.

Comment: how do we go about including a second optional condition in addition to "NEW", I need to also include "EC". Thanks in advance!

Comment: i figured it out with `(?:NEW |EC )?`